# how to push return value from onload function to global variable

Tags: javascript, variables, return, global, onload

```
var myids = '';

function passid(){
    onload = function () {
        uidt = tempid.ssid; // some value getting from API
    }
}

passid();
console.log(myids);
```

Can Anyone help me with this,  How to push  **uitd** to var **myids** so I can be use wherever I want.

Comment: It's unclear what issue you're actually having. If `tempid.ssid` is coming from an async function, then see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992).

Answer (score 0):

Your API request is definitely asynchronous, so you can use the [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise?retiredLocale=it) via async await if you are inside an asynchronous function or then and catche if you are outside an asynchronous function

```js
var mydata = '';

async function apiReq(){
  
  return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(response=>response.json()).then(response=>{
    mydata = response
    console.log("test");
    console.log(mydata);
  
  })
  


}


apiReq().then(response => {
  console.log("request is ok")
  console.log(mydata);

});
```